# Qt demo with Arabic support

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am new to Qt, I need to develop application which will have all strings in Arabic i.e. application title, button labels in short everything.

It is mentioned Qt does support RTL language, but I am not able to find demo or a basic working example, if someone got some example which shows how I can render RTL language in Qt or refer to some good tutorial, would be really helpful!

Comment: I would love to hear why you think this question is off-topic and need to be closed? If you dont know something it does not mean no one can ask it or should not be on stackoverflow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setLayoutDirection api will do the job, that is the magic of Qt Layout management feature. Means all the widgets which display arabic language need to manage with Qt Layout.

```
setLayoutDirection(tr("LTR")=="RTL" ? Qt::RightToLeft : Qt::LeftToRight)
```

[image]
Example from Qt [Qt I18n Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-i18n.html)
SO[Layout direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365753/layout-direction-for-arabic-is-not-determined-based-on-the-locale-mac-and-linux)