# Arabic string displaying on QLabel and QPushtbuon is different in Qt

Tags: qt, arabic, qlabel

There is one Arabic string as: اختبار عرض اللغة العربية في QTE.
The displaying on `QLabel` and `QPushButton` is different with same interface `setText()`.
See picture below:

[image]

Anyone can help on why the displaying behavior is different?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

possibly you need to change the direction of the layout. in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365753/layout-direction-for-arabic-is-not-determined-based-on-the-locale-mac-and-linux)

```
setLayoutDirection(tr("LTR")=="RTL" ? Qt::RightToLeft : Qt::LeftToRight)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
It seems that it takes effect when use qApp->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft).
But this will also affect the overall application layout.

Here I only want to change the string direction on QPushButton to make it same as QLabel.
However qPushButton->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft) doesn't have effect.